# Python: How can I split the string properly to save in the format of csv?

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to save my string in the format of csv.
The string looks like this, line separated by '\n',:

```
12,12,11,13,11,12
21,15,21,23,41,26
34,16,46,17,21,15
44,17,22,39,10,13
```

and so on. Also I have a manually written list of headers like

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```

When I tried to write this using the csv writer,

```
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvwriter:
    writer = csv.writer(csvwriter, dialect='excel')
    writer.writerow(header) # write header
    for r in output.splitlines():
        writer.writerows(r)
    csvwriter.close()
```

But when I look up the output file,

```
A,B,C,D,E,F
1
2
","
1
2
","
1
1
","
... (and so on)
```

Why this happens and how can I fix this? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your string is like this:

```
string = '''12,12,11,13,11,12
21,15,21,23,41,26
34,16,46,17,21,15
44,17,22,39,10,13'''
headers = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```

without any library:

```
with open('untitled.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(','.join(headers)+'\n')
    for line in string:
        f.write(line)
```

You can make it into a pandas csv and then save:

```
import pandas as pd
data = []
for i in string.split('\n'):
    data.append(i.split(','))
csv = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=headers)

csv.to_csv('path_to_save', index=False)
```

Comment: I wouldn't want to import another library just to export csv.

Comment: added an option without any library too

Comment: This works perfect. I'm not sure why my code didn't work. Do you have any clue?

Comment: Your string is already separated with lines but you are also doing `for r in output.splitlines():`. I thing the splitlines here is splitting the string further into single characters? If you just loop over output without splitlines, it should work too.

Comment: One more thing... if you are using `with open....`, you don't need to close the file as it will happen itself after the `with` context is over.